# Store Step Function and Lamda in same code commit repo

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-codecommit

I am creating a step function that orchestrates a lamda. The lamda has 4 simple endpoints.

I would like to save the lamda and step function in the same git repo. Regarding this:

1. Is this good practice or should they be in separate repos on code commit?
2. If this is good practice, what is the best way to manage the deploy pipeline - for two related projects in the same repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best practice to have actual code and necessary infrastructure code in same repo.

**Creating infrastructure as code**:

There are many options, couple of widely used ones are:

- [Cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)
- [Aws CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html)

In general writing CDK code is easier than cloudformation and writing [step functions in CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-readme.html) is a million times easier.

So, my recommendation is to write CDK code to create Lambda functions and step functions.

**Build & Deploy:**

We can use [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) to build artifacts and [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) to orchestrate.

Comment: thanks this is perfect. For anyone looking for a tutorial, this 5 part series is ideal: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2019/11/aws-cdk-part-5-create-step-functions/

Comment: When you deploy an RDS through CDK, and you store data to it - what happens when you re-deploy? Does aws destroy your previous set up and recreate it, with the data deleted?

Comment: @hitwill When we redeploy, if nothing was changed for that resource, cdk will not do anything. If you make some changes to RDS resource, it will be updated, if you make some major change that needs resource doesn't support, example change from mysql to postgres (just an example), that needs replacement of the resource, in cloudformation, typically database is deleted unless DeletePolicy is setup, but in CDK by default DeletePolicy is setup, so the RDS instance will never be accidentally deleted.

Comment: Stack update behaviour is more documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html). In short cdk generates cloudformation with all the best practices in place.

Comment: Thank you - this greatly helps

Answer (score 0):

After research, another option I found was to use [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-step-functions). I think its definitions are simpler and it's also easier to test offline. Credit to the accepted answer, as it's also a useful resource.